# How to secure Elmah.axd in Web Api project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, elmah

I am using this Elmah package for logging unhandled exception in Web Api Project.

https://github.com/rdingwall/elmah-contrib-webapi/issues/18

The package works great with Web API and it successfully able to log all unhandled exception to Elmah, however little worry about securing Elmah.axd though. I am using Asp.Net Identity Token Bearer authentication for making API calls, so the default security mechanism not be valid in my case. Any idea how could I secure in my case, I want to allow this only to a user who has in admin role. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I have figured two ways of overcoming the issue with token, but both of them are flawed in some ways, though, but usable:

1. Elmah.mvc allows you to decide on the url that you want to use, so if you disallow access to the original elmah by disabling access to /elmah url and instead add an appsetting for the elmah.mvc like that:

```cs
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah_very_secure_url"/>
```

Then by providing a more secure/random url you can be the only one who is able to access it. This approach has some security flaws because it's relying on the secret url, but many sites actually do use this approach when they send you the url only you can use to logon, etc. More information can be found on security.stackexchange.com regarding how secure this approach is and what are the implications

2. Doing your own method that you can call from console to provide the Authentication header that is required. It can look something like that for angular (the idea is just that you use the framework that does the interception of the request already to add token and utilize it to issue get to elmah):

```js
function elmah(){
    angular.element(document.body)
           .injector()
           .get("$http")
           .get("\elmah")
           .success(function(response)
           {
               var elmahWindow = window.open("");
               elmahWindow.document.write(response);
           });
};
```

Then if you type elmah() in the console, you will have a new window opened. This approach seem to be secure enough (unless you change the method to accept some parameters that can be then abused in xss or something), but the problem is that you can only see the original view in elmah and clicking on all of the urls will fail. It can be extended in various ways, but I don't see an easy convenient way for fixing it.